# Newbie question: running a custom script in terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am complete new to Ubuntu, so please take it slowly:  I'm trying to datamosh a video for my glitchart work and I've found a script (I THINK it's called script) for doing just that. But just can't figure out how to make this thing work. The script I'm trying to run was downloaded from here https://github.com/ucnv/aviglitch

Any ideas?

Vladi

Comment: Yes it is a script. But it is probably easier to get it going by following the readme ;) See below. Please drop me a comment if in doubt or edit your question if you got more information.

Answer (score 0):

[Installation](https://github.com/ucnv/aviglitch/blob/master/README.rdoc) (so no downloading yourself):

```
gem install aviglitch
```

After that you can do this from command line:

```
datamosh /path/to/your.avi -o /path/to/broken.avi
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Rinzwind, so if I got it right I should run installation and not download it, cuz right now connecting PC that runs ubuntu is another problem.... It's doesn't recognize my internet connection .... Is there a way to run this script offline? I've downloaded it and it's in ubuntu already

Comment: Ubuntu, world, anyone?

Comment: always prioritize: getting wireless/internet working is prio 1. If fixed the installation for this gets easy. Thing is: what you probably need is the whole program and not just 1 script. And you probably need to compile it or put it in all the correct places. Lots of hassle ;)

Comment: Trying to connect it...hell:(